# Collectd and Nginx plugin not working

Tags: nginx, collectd

My collectd config looks like:

```
LoadPlugin nginx
...
<Plugin "nginx">
    URL "http://localhost:8080/nginx_status?auto"
</Plugin>
```

Nginx conf looks like:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  index index.html index.htm;
  server_name localhost;
  root  /var/www/default/;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location /nginx_status {
    stub_status on;
    access_log   off;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
  }
}
```

When i execute

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/nginx_status?auto
```

it outputs:

```
Active connections: 1 
server accepts handled requests
 56 56 322 
Reading: 0 Writing: 1 Waiting: 0
```

But when open graphite there is no nginx graph avaliable.
Collectd and Nginx was restarted many times. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finaly resolved. After logfile plugin turned on:

```
LoadPlugin logfile

<Plugin logfile>
    LogLevel info
    File "/var/log/collectd.log"
    Timestamp true
</Plugin>
```

I found that nginx plugin is not installed:

```
[2014-10-14 06:30:59] plugin_load: Could not find plugin "nginx" in /usr/lib64/collectd
[2014-10-14 06:30:59] Found a configuration for the `nginx' plugin, but the plugin isn't loaded or didn't register a configuration callback.
```

Simply execute (AMI):

```
$ sudo yum install collectd-nginx
```

And all works perfectly

Comment: I don't know why, but after activating the log to folder plugin my network plugin started to work too.